# Library module access to resources

Tags: android, module, android-resources, android-library

I have project with simple following structure:

[image: Project structure]

As you can see the mylibrary module has auto generated a res folder. How I can get acess from some mylibrary code to resources? Does libraries have their own context? What mechanism is used to acсess resources that are located in library res folder from it's code? Is it possible?

Comment: you need any `Context`, and then you can access any resources. Just pass `Context` from the app to the library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Library resources are merged with the app resources (example: AppCompat) when compiled into the APK.

Just access it like any other resource.